How should I route the EN pin of the LMR51430?
I am using a LMR51430(datasheet) buck converter to get +5V from a +12V battery. I followed the recommended layout from the datasheet, but the problem is this design doesn't specify how we should connect the EN(VINN) pin. I am wondering if my approach is alright or will I run into problems?
TI's recommended layout from the datasheet:

My layout:





Is the source (MCU?) very far away?

@winny the MCU is  ~3 cm away. By the source do you mean the +12V battery? (the battery connector is ~1cm away from the buck converter)

As CL writes below, most probably not an issue being 3 cm away. I once did have an EMC issue with the EN pin and had to put a small low-pass filter in front of it (two layer only and more distance than that). If your design passes EMC, no issues. If you trigger EN to go off, filter or tighten up the design.

@winny Thank you for the help!

The EN pin signal has a constant voltage and is connected to a low-impedance voltage source (VIN), so it is pretty much immune to noise, and conversely will not affect other signals.
So its routing does not matter. You can just as well route it directly under the chip.

Thank you so much for the help!
